# Unit test for method containing switch case statement and insert to db

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, switch-statement, apache-poi

I have a method that contains a switch case block which iterates through an excel file to obtain values to write to a db.
I need to write a unit test for this method but I have no idea where to start.
Below is the method of which I need to write the unit test for. If anyone could advise me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public void loadAccount() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement insert = null;
    Properties props = new Properties();

    try {
        conn = connMan.allocateConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        insert = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL_TOP_ACCOUNTS);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("path");
        props.load(inputStream);
        String excelFilePath = props.getProperty("Account");
        FileInputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(iStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        // Current date for entry into db
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        insert.setDate(1, sqlDate);

        // Skips the header row
        iterator.next();

        // Iterate through the first sheet and get the cell values
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    String institution = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    insert.setString(2, institution);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Formatting data because of alphanumeric mix in row
                    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                    String dept = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    insert.setString(3, dept);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int hits = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    insert.setInt(4, hits);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    int visitors = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    insert.setInt(5, visitors);
                    break;
                }
            }
            insert.addBatch();
        }
        int[] insertCount = insert.executeBatch();
        int successInserted = 0;
        for (int item : insertCount) {
            if (item == 1) {
                successInserted++;
            }
        }

        log.info("There're " + insertCount.length + " need to be inserted, with successfully [" + successInserted
                + "] inserted");
        conn.commit();          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception in loadAccount:" + e);
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            log.error("Exception when rollback the loading.", e1);
            throw e1;
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        connMan.closeStatement(insert);
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                connMan.deallocateConnection(conn);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Exception in loadAccount:" + e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No check on missing cells, no `insert.clearParameters()`. You might want to split functionality, to make first an Excel reader that delivers a `Stream<InsertParams>` to be tested with all kind of Excel docs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to faciliate easy testing, you should make sure (as in "refactor until") your method does only one thing (reading an excel file, extracting values and writing to a db are at least three things). Going the Test-Driven-Development-Path would have left you with these separate methods in first place.

Then you should grab your prefered mocking framework and mock away the db access since using a real db would be an integration test and not an unit test.

After that you should test your new methods one by one. Preferably you added one 'mastermind' that faciliates calling the other methods and collectiong results so you could test your methods without invoking the others. Call your methods with fixed values (preferably edge and error cases) and use your prefered unit testing framework to assert the returns.

Comment: So I should split the above method into 3 separate methods to make it easier to perform testing on?

Comment: 4 at least... at least 3 doing what needs to be done and one calling the others.